# how to use merge in daml contract map value?

Tags: haskell, daml

```
MapKey k => (k -> a -> Optional c) -> (k -> b -> Optional c) -> (k -> a -> b -> Optional c) -> Map k a -> Map k b -> Map k c
```

difficult to understand syntax please provide example for declaring this merge for map values and also provide brief description how to construct it with simple examples

Comment: This seems to be a carbon copy of a question asked on the DAML forum: https://discuss.daml.com/t/how-to-achive-foldl-operation-for-map-data/1557/7

Comment: @bame it would be request from non native daml developer ,it would be helpful if daml documentation have some example approaches like this ,so it will be ease for beginners understanding like me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have a read of the [docs](https://docs.daml.com/daml/stdlib/DA-Next-Map.html#function-da-next-map-merge-2656) for the function.

`merge` takes three functions and two maps. The two maps have the same key type, but different value types. The map resulting form `merge` has to have a single value type, of course, so we have to tell merge what to do if

1. Only a value in the first supplied map is present
2. Only a value int he second supplied map is present
3. Both values are present

Let's for example say we have a map `Map Int Text` and a map `Map Int Bool` which we want to merge, and let's just say the resulting map should indicate in which of the three cases above we are. We can define a type for that:

```
data EitherOrBoth a b
  = EOBLeft a
  | EOBRight b
  | EOBBoth (a, b)
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Now we can define functions to say "Stick a value in Left", "Stick a value in Right", and "Stick two values in a tuple" in merge:

```
mergeWithBoth : (MapKey k) => Map k a -> Map k b -> Map k (EitherOrBoth a b)
mergeWithBoth = merge (\k x -> Some (EOBLeft x)) (\k y -> Some (EOBRight y)) (\k x y -> Some (EOBBoth (x, y)))
```

Try the whole thing out using a script:

```
import Daml.Script
import DA.Next.Map (Map, MapKey, merge, fromList)

data EitherOrBoth a b
  = EOBLeft a
  | EOBRight b
  | EOBBoth (a, b)
    deriving (Eq, Show)

mergeWithBoth : (MapKey k) => Map k a -> Map k b -> Map k (EitherOrBoth a b)
mergeWithBoth = merge (\k x -> Some (EOBLeft x)) (\k y -> Some (EOBRight y)) (\k x y -> Some (EOBBoth (x, y)))

testMerge = script do
  let
    mapIntText : Map Int Text = fromList[(1, "Hello"), (2, "World")]
    mapIntDec : Map Int Bool  = fromList[(2, True), (3, False)]

  assert (mergeWithBoth mapIntText mapIntDec
    == fromList [(1, EOBLeft "Hello"),(2, EOBBoth ("World", True)), EOBRight False)])
  
  return (mergeWithBoth mapIntText mapIntDec)
```

Comment: thanks for u example,is it possible to do without using list

Comment: It's possible to instantiate Maps without going via lists, but it's awkward. Just chain calls to `Map.insert`, starting with `Map.empty`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two maps with the same key type

```
m1 : Map k a
m2 : Map k b
```

You can merge them into a single map `Map k c` calling `merge` like this:

```
merge f1 f2 f12 m1 m2
```

where

- `f1 : k -> a -> Optional c` specifies what to do if a key was found in `m1` but not in `m2`. Here `f1` is passed both the key and its corresponding value in `m1`.
- `f2 : k -> b -> Optional c` specifies what to do if a key was found in `m2` but not in `m1`. Here `f2` is passed both the key and its corresponding value in `m2`.
- `f12 : k -> a -> b -> Optional c` specifies what to do if a key was found in both `m1` and `m2`. Here `f12` is passed the key, its corresponding value in `m1`, and its corresponding value in `m2`.

In each case, return `None` is you want the key to be missing in the result map. Return `Some x` if you want the the key to be present and associated to value `x`.